# Converting week number and year back to date format

Tags: r, date, as.date

Although I found solutions on this question, in my case, code returns only `NA`s. What's wrong?
Working example below:

```
df <- data.frame("date" = seq(as.Date("2015/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"), by = "day"))
df$week <- format(df$date, "%W-%Y")
str(df)

# week back into proper date
df$week_date <- as.Date(paste0("01-", df$week), format = "%w-%W-%Y")
str(df)
```

Comment: It looks like if you take the leading zero out, that it mostly works... `as.Date(paste0("1-", df$week), format = "%w-%W-%Y")`

Comment: It looks like it doesn't know how to handle when a week = 0, so you still get NA for those cases.

Answer (score 0):

@cory: your answer is correct and led me to find the solution.
R documentation for `strptime` says:

> `%w` Weekday as decimal number (0--6, Sunday is 0).
>
> `%W` Week of the year as decimal number (00--53) using Monday as the
> first day of week (and typically with the first Monday of the year as
> day 1 of week 1). The UK convention.

So, this works as expected after `paste0` only single digit:

```
df <- data.frame("date" = seq(as.Date("2014/1/1"), as.Date("2016/1/1"), by = "day"))
df$week <- format(df$date, "%W-%Y")
str(df)

# week back into proper date
df$week_date <- as.Date(paste0("1-", df$week), format = "%w-%W-%Y")

str(df)
View(df)
```

Worth noting, days that fall before the first Monday of any new year land in *no man's land*, thus require individual approach.